# How to produce the indexes from pdist2 function in Octave?

Tags: matlab, indexing, octave, euclidean-distance, pdist

The Matlab function as the `pdist2` function that can compute the distance between each row in e.g `L2-norm`. GNU Octave have the same function `pdist2`.

The difference between those function is that Matlab can return the indexes `[D, I] = pdist2(X, Y, 'norm')` while GNU Octave can only return the distances `[D] = pdist2(X, Y, 'norm')`.

**Question:**

Assume that you have matrix `X`

```
X = [-0.2515    1.0451   -1.2817
     -1.9741    0.2782   -1.0234
     10.6772   10.7365    9.9264
      8.7785   11.1680    9.5915
    -34.2330  -30.8410  -31.7200
    -32.6290  -31.7860  -31.2900
     45.0000   43.0000         0
     23.0000   -3.0000    2.0000];
```

And you are using `D = pdist2(X, X, "euclidean")` for the ecluidian distance

```
D = [0.0000000       1.9032127       18.4114208      17.3850403      55.6593018      55.0153084      61.7215919      23.8278294
     1.9032127       0.0000000       19.7314529      18.6247940      54.3260574      53.7019653      63.5040855      25.3691425
     18.4114208      19.7314529      0.0000000       1.9757286       74.0272751      73.3647156      48.1406441      20.0840893
     17.3850403      18.6247940      1.9757286       0.0000000       72.9478302      72.3251266      49.1657410      21.4619255
     55.6593018      54.3260574      74.0272751      72.9478302      0.0000000       1.9108551       112.8561935     72.0262222
     55.0153084      53.7019653      73.3647156      72.3251266      1.9108551       0.0000000       112.2420197     70.9326706
     61.7215919      63.5040855      48.1406441      49.1657410      112.8561935     112.2420197     0.0000000       51.0294037
     23.8278294      25.3691425      20.0840893      21.4619255      72.0262222      70.9326706      51.0294037      0.0000000];
```

How can I produce the indexes `I` if I don't have the access through the `pdist2` function?

Comment: What exact Matlab code do you want to replicate in Octave? `[D, I] = pdist2(X, X, 'euclidean')` gives an error in Matlab, because additional input arguments need to be specified (which will also affect output `D`)

Comment: There’s no Index because `D` is a full array with row index being the row index of `x` and the column index being the row index of `y`.

Comment: There is also no `'norm'` metric in Octave.

Comment: @LuisMendo look at this link were it explains the incidens. https://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html#d126e814656

Comment: Please post the `I` matrix given by MATLAB for the example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following are 3 methods and they are tested for performance over a **10k** square matrix.

#### Iteration 1

With `sort()`, takes **~1.11 seconds**

```matlab
function nearest_indices = find_nearest_indices(D)
    % Find the indices of the nearest points for each point in the matrix.
    % Args:
    % D : A square matrix containing distances between points.
    % Returns:
    % An array of indices of the nearest points.
    % Usage:
    % nearest_indices = find_nearest_indices(D);

    % Number of rows in D
    n = size(D, 1);
    
    % Preallocate array for indices
    nearest_indices = zeros(n, 1);

    for i = 1:n
        % Sort the distances in the current row
        [sorted_distances, sorted_indices] = sort(D(i, :));

        % Find the index of the nearest neighbor
        % The first element in sorted_indices is the point itself, so we take the second element
        nearest_indices(i) = sorted_indices(2);
    end
end
```

#### Iteration 2

Without `sort()`, takes **~1.08 seconds**

```matlab
function nearest_indices = find_nearest_indices(D)
    % Number of rows in D
    n = size(D, 1);
    
    % Preallocate array for indices
    nearest_indices = zeros(n, 1);
    for i = 1:n
        % Copy the row and set the diagonal element (self-distance) to Inf
        row = D(i, :);
        row(i) = Inf;

        % Find the index of the minimum non-zero distance
        [~, min_index] = min(row);
        nearest_indices(i) = min_index;
    end
end
```

#### Iteration 3

Without a `for loop`, takes **~0.55 seconds**

```
function nearest_indices = find_nearest_indices(D)
    % Set the diagonal elements to Inf to ignore self-distances
    n = size(D, 1);
    D(sub2ind(size(D), 1:n, 1:n)) = Inf;

    % Find the index of the minimum non-zero distance in each row
    [~, nearest_indices] = min(D, [], 2);
end
```

Comment: Using a sort function is very expensive! Trust me, I have tried that

Comment: Actually the bottle neck here is not the `sort()` as much as it's the `for` loop itself, as Octave is designed for vector operations

Comment: Yes, but implement that in other languages, is expensive.

Comment: @euraad There's a reason that MATLAB is proprietary and licensed whilst Octave is not, it may not be possible to achieve the same performance as MATLAB without writing compiled libraries to achieve the functionality you want - MATLAB itself calls a compiled mex when you use `pdist2` for any of the in-built distance measures. You asked how to achieve the output, weshouman has shown you how...